# Will Amazon S3 comply with the UK Data Protection Act?

Tags: amazon-s3, data-protection

In order for our product to comply with the UK Data Protection Act, one requirement is that our data must be stored within a UK data centre.

Is there a facility to configure Amazon S3 to use a UK-based data centre?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is fundamentally a legal question, not an administration one.

Comment: AWS's list of regions is public. They do, however, participate in the EU's Safe Harbor program (http://aws.amazon.com/privacy/) which may suffice.

Comment: Not sure if this is misunderstanding of requirements.  The ICO approves of using the major cloud operators EU regions for most data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current list presented to me in the AWS console is:

- US East (N. Virginia)
- US West (Oregon)
- US West (N. California)
- EU (Ireland)
- Asia Pacific (Singapore)
- Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
- Asia Pacific (Sydney)
- South America (São Paulo)

So no, there's no UK option.  That said, and bearing in mind that we are **not** legal experts here and do **not** do legal advice, I'd be very surprised if "*inside the EU*" was not enough to satisfy your requirements.  Check your requirements carefully, and if inside the EU will do, pick Ireland.